# Newer javascript gui/form builder Extjs

Tags: extjs

Is there any newer gui and form builder, possibly with charting, newer than ExtJs 4 or more fully featured?

Because it seems extjs is it.

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean by gui and form builder, have you taken a look as ExtJS Designer? - http://www.sencha.com/products/designer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one else seems to be forthcoming, I will confirm your supposition: ExtJS is the latest.

Comment: ExtJS is the framework, and there is no form builder in the framework.  There is a tool called Sencha Architect that can build forms with a gui, but it's not just for forms, but for full applications, but editing just forms 'could' be done.